# Finding the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1+z+z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Show that  $\frac{1}{1+z+z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^{3n} - z^{3n+1})$ for the disc $|z|<1$.

I've tried doing this to no avail. One way I tried was to factor out the polynomial in the denominator and perform partial fractions, then using the geometric series... but it looks really ugly and I can't think of a way to simplify it. (I tried taking cases when $k$ is a multiple of $6$ but still...)
This is what I ended up with:
$$-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\left[e^{-i\pi /6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac{z}{e^{5\pi /6 i}}\right)^k+ e^{-5i\pi /6 }\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{e^{5i \pi /6}}\right)^k\right]$$

Comment: Start with the right-hand side.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I tried but I got $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(z^{3 n}-z^{3 n+1}\right)=\frac{z^3}{z^2+z+1}$$
I am not the only one as far as I can see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bz%5E(3+n)+-+z%5E(3+n+%2B+1),+%7Bn,+1,+Infinity%7D%5D

Comment: So your original formula was wrong...

Comment: Sorry it should be starting from $n=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the series for $$\frac1{1-z^3}=\frac1{(1-z)(1+z+z^2)}$$ and multiply by $1-z$.

Comment: How would I find the series for the LHS? I feel like there wouldn't be an obvious pattern for the nth derivative of the LHS to put under the sum.

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Ever heard of a geometric series?

Comment: Yes but I can't see how it's used for that here. $1+z+z^2 = \frac{z^3 - 1}{z-1}$ but that's already been used, so not sure how to find the series for a cubic in the denominator.

Comment: Oh, I see it, thank you.